# What is maximum number of IRQs supported by Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt, interrupt-handling

From [kernel version 4.9](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/9/14/431), we will be able to see directory for each interrupt under `/sys/kernel/irq`.

1. What is maximum number of directories we can see under `/sys/kernel/irq`?
2. Will the number of directories under `/sys/kernel/irq` will be constant for a particular system? (I have observed this as constant per system, but I'm not sure)
3. For each IRQ, `/sys/kernel/irq/*/name` file will hold constant name
   for e.g. for IRQ 7, we will have directory `/sys/kernel/irq/7/`
   Now `/sys/kernel/irq/7/name` will hold constant value forever for that system?
4. What about other files under same directory such as `actions, chip_name, per_cpu_count, type`?

Comment: Is this for a particular architecture (x86_64, ARM, etc.)?  Or are you looking for an absolute maximum?

Comment: 1. As many as architecture / platform supports. I have heard of 4096.

Comment: 2. No, you can't fully rely on it. Imagine when you have two drivers for the same device. You remove one module and insert another. In general they might have different rules how to create that name.

Answer (score 0):

1. This number will change depending on hardware architecture.
2. This number will change if someone adds a new module which will be registering a new IRQ, or if someone removes the module which has already registered an IRQ.
3. Will change if someone removes the module, which is using this IRQ, and register another module which has same IRQ.
4. Only `per_cpu_count` value will increase according to number of times the interrupt is fired.